# An algorithm to solve an equation with modulo?

Tags: modular-arithmetic

given

$(2n + 1) \mod k = n \mod k $

where $k$ is known

what's an algorithm to find $n$ ?

Comment: There is none, since there is no unique solution. All you know is that $n\equiv-1\mod k$, or in other words, that $k\mid n+1$.

Comment: @DonThousand, what does $k | n + 1$ mean? Sorry, I don't get the first expression either. Yes, there's no unique solution, but is there a way to find *a* solution?

Comment: $n=k-1$ is a solution. $k\mid n+1$ means that $k$ is a divisor of $n+1$.

Comment: "Sorry, I don't get the first expression either."   The fiirst expression is $n\equiv -1 \pmod k$.  You say you don't get it but you used the very same notation and concepts when you wrote $(2n+1) \pmod k = n\pmod k$.  How can you use the expression if you don't get it?

Comment: $K|n+1$ means $k$ divides evenly into $n+1$.  So for example if $k =37$ for example $37|n+1$ so $n +1 = 37$ or $n+1 = 74$ or $n+1 = 111$ or $n+1 = 0$ or $n + 1 = -37$ etc. etc etc  Which mean $n = 36$ or $73$ or $110$ or $-1$ or $-38$ or etc. etc. etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$2n +1 \equiv n \pmod k$  (you don't have to write $\mod k$ after every clause.

$(2n+1)-n \equiv n-n \pmod k$

$n +1 \equiv 0 \pmod k$

$n \equiv -1 \pmod k$.

So $-1 + mk$ for every integer is a solutions.  $n=-1$ is a solution.  $n = k -1$ is a solution $n = 3k -1$ is a solution.

All this solutions as a group $\{......, -k-1, -1, k-1, 2k-1, 3k-1,....\}$ are consider the solution.  We say this is the equivalence class of $-1$ and all those numbers are basically considered to be the same thing.

=====

Okay..... less abstract and more basic.

$2n+1 \mod k = n \mod  k$ means that there is some integer $m$ where

$2n + 1 = n + m\times k$.

So $n = -1 + m\times k$.  Now any $m$ will yield a solution.

$n = -1 + m\times k$ for any integer $m$.